# Bridging header doesn't work with two frameworks (Flurry)

Tags: objective-c, swift, flurry

I have a bridging header in my project (named "Antoine Bellanger-Bridging-Header.h" if this helps) and then when I import my first framework

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

everything works.
But when I import the second one

```
#import "Flurry.h"
```

I have two errors :

```
Flurry.h file not found 
Swift Compiler Error : Failed to import bridging header "/Path"
```

I would like to know if the compiler error could be caused by the first error ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT : I have tried this with another project and I have the same error. May it come from the Flurry files ?

@BC_Dilum : Flurry.h is a file that I want to import and from the documentation of the site, it should be included like that. See https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/

Comment: What is this Flurry.h? Is it in a path like "Flurry/Flurry.h"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. I just made a mistake and @BC_Dilum was right by adding

`#import "Flurry/Flurry.h"`

and not just `#import Flurry.h`